# Is it possible to create an XSD schema for an XSD schema, or place restrictions on element definitions? How?

Tags: xml, xsd

My goal is to place a simple restriction on my XSD element definitions: I want to define an element so that

1. `<xs:annotation><xs:documentation>` is reqired for all element definitions`</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>`
2. "declared" and "last_modified" attributes are added to the `<xs:element>` and "note_author" and "note_added" attributes are added to the `<xs:documentation>` element.

With what I have below, I am able to get Schema 2 to validate, but I am unable to enforce the rules that I mentioned above, which I would like to declare in Schema 1.

Example of what I want to achieve with the modified, validated XSD schema (Schema 2):

Schema2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:ds="http://documentation_schema">

  <xs:import namespace="http://documentation_schema" 
             schemaLocation="documentation_schema.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="document" 
              ds:created="2013-06-20" 
              ds:last_modified="2013-06-20">

    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation ds:note_author="xsd_user1" 
                        ds:note_added="2013-06-20">
      The root element for a document
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>

    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="subelement"/>
      </xs:sequence>    
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="subelement" type="xs:string"  
              ds:created="2013-06-20" 
              ds:last_modified="2013-07-20">

    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation ds:note_author="xsd_user1" 
                        ds:note_added="2013-06-20">
      A subelement child of document
      </xs:documentation>

      <xs:documentation ds:note_author="xsd_user2" 
                        ds:note_added="2013-07-20">
      changed from complex to string type
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>`
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Schema 1 (documentation_schema) -- the schema that I want to do the validating of Schema 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="http://documentation_schema">

  <xs:attribute name="created" type="xs:date"/>

  <xs:attribute name="last_modified" type="xs:date"/>

  <xs:attribute name="note_added" type="xs:date"/>

  <xs:attribute name="note_author">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:enumeration value="xsd_user1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="xsd_user2"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4):

Nice question!

Several points should be made:

- First, as I guess you already know (though some readers of the question and this answer may not), your schema document 1 is already legal as it sits.  So you don't *need* to modify the schema for schema documents in order to make it legal.  If I understand you correctly, however, you want it not just to be valid; you want the variant of it in which element declarations occur without xs:documentation elements, or without ds:added and ds:last_modified attributes, to be *invalid*.
- Second, it is possible to modify the XSD schema for XSD schema documents in the way you describe, and it is in principle possible to validate your schema documents against the modified schema for schema documents.

  But schema validators are allowed to have built-in knowledge of some schema components in arbitrary namespaces, and they are *required* to have built-in knowledge of the XSD namespace.  So it is possible for conforming schema validators to see a request to validate schema document 1, say "Aha, I already know all I need to know about namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, I don't need to read the schema document the user supplied", and then not enforce the additional constraints you have specified.

  Concretely, in my tests, I was able to use Xerces J to validate schema documents against a modified schema for schema documents, but Saxon seemed to ignore the modifications and rule the schema documents valid even when element declarations lacked the required attributes.
- Similarly, it is not possible, when validating documents against the schemas you write, to require your XSD validators to object to schema documents that don't meet your heightened requirements.

With those background points out of the way, here is what you need to do.

1. You do *not* need to import the ds schema into your schema document 1.  Importing it means that you can add references to the attributes ds:added, etc., to the types you declare in schema document 1 -- that is, it imports it into the schema being defined for the target namespace.  It has no effect on the schema used to validate schema documents (which is a schema for the namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema).
2. You need to create a schema that modifies the standard schema for schema documents, and not just by adding new components but by redefining or overriding components in the existing schema for schema documents.  There are two ways to do this:  using xs:redefine, and (in XSD 1.1) using xs:override.  In XSD 1.1, xs:redefine is deprecated, because its specification has proven to be incomplete and/or inconsistent, and interoperability across processors is poor for some ways of using it.
3. You need to use an XSD validator to validate your schema documents against your modified schema for schema documents.  As noted above, this may not work with all validators.  If you have trouble making your XSD validator handle the case, you may want to consider writing a Schematron schema to enforce the few constraints you mention, and building Schematron validation into your work flow.  (One of the advantages of Schematron is that validating just a few isolated aspects of a document is quite easy.  That may be a drawback in some situations, but not in this one or in other cases where one wants a little incremental increase in validation.  And if as your user name suggests you are an XSLT users, Schematron is likely to feel quite natural to you.)

As a test, I've used xs:override to modify the schema for schema documents for XSD 1.1; the schema document is shown below, and the comments will, I hope, make reasonably clear what is going on.  If you have access only to an XSD 1.0 processor, you will need to use xs:redefine instead; some details will change.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:ds="http://documentation_schema"
           blockDefault="#all"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xml:lang="en"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="Id: structures.xsd,v 1.2 2004/01/15 11:34:25 ht Exp ">

  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      This schema document redefines some things in the schema for 
      schema documents.  
      First we import the ds and xml namespaces.
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
  <xs:import namespace="http://documentation_schema"
             schemaLocation="xslt_user_schema2.xsd">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Get access to the ds:* attributes.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:import>

  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      Then we include the schema for schema documents defines in XSD 1.1, with
      some modifications.  
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>

  <xs:override schemaLocation="sfsd-11.xsd">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        The schema document "sfsd-11.xsd" is our local copy of the 
        XSD 1.1 schema for schema documents.  
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>

    <xs:element name="documentation" id="documentation" 
                type="xs:documentation-extended">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
          Here, we change the xs:documentation element from using
          a local complex type to using a named type (declared below).  
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="annotation" id="annotation">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
          Next, we require xs:annotation elements to contain 
          at least one xs:documentation element.
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>

      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:openAttrs">
            <!--* modified the content model to require at least one 
                * occurrence of xs:documentation 
                *-->
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="xs:appinfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element ref="xs:documentation"/>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="xs:appinfo"/>
                <xs:element ref="xs:documentation"/>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>            
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!--* Finally, we override the complex type used for all forms 
        * of element declarations, by including the attribute group
        * xs:schema-documentation-attributes (defined below).
        * Note that we cannot include references to the attributes
        * directly, because the default schema for schema documents
        * doesn't import the ds namespace.  One level of indirection,
        * however, suffices to solve the problem.
        *-->

    <xs:complexType name="element" abstract="true">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
          The element element can be used either
          at the top level to define an element-type binding globally,
          or within a content model to either reference a globally-defined
          element or type or declare an element-type binding locally.
        The ref form is not allowed at the top level.</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation>
          This modification of the type adds two required attributes:
          ds:added and ds:last_modified.  They will be inherited by
          all the various restrictions of this type.
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:annotated">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
              <xs:element name="simpleType" type="xs:localSimpleType"/>
              <xs:element name="complexType" type="xs:localComplexType"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="alternative" type="xs:altType" 
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:group ref="xs:identityConstraint" minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attributeGroup ref="xs:defRef"/>
          <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:QName"/>

          <xs:attribute name="substitutionGroup">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:list itemType="xs:QName"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
          <xs:attributeGroup ref="xs:occurs"/>
          <xs:attribute name="default" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:attribute name="fixed" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:attribute name="nillable" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
          <xs:attribute name="abstract" type="xs:boolean" default="false"
                        use="optional"/>
          <xs:attribute name="final" type="xs:derivationSet"/>
          <xs:attribute name="block" type="xs:blockSet"/>
          <xs:attribute name="form" type="xs:formChoice"/>
          <xs:attribute name="targetNamespace" type="xs:anyURI"/>
          <!--* add the ds:* attributes *-->
          <xs:attributeGroup ref="xs:schema-documentation-attributes"/>
          <!--* end of added material. *-->
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:override>

  <xs:complexType name="documentation-extended" mixed="true">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        This complex type is just like the usual type for the 
        xs:documentation element, except that it reuqires the 
        ds:note_author and ds:note_added attributes.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:any processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="source" type="xs:anyURI"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
    <!--* additions ... *-->
    <xs:attribute ref="ds:note_author" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="ds:note_added" use="required"/>
    <!--* end added material *-->
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="schema-documentation-attributes">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        This attribute group serves to include the two
        attributes specified in the complex type for
        element declarations.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attribute ref="ds:created" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="ds:last_modified" use="required"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup> 

</xs:schema>
```

---

*Addition* in response to comments.

> 1(a). I still need to have a local copy of the schema used to validate schema documents, right? (in your case: sfsd-11.xsd, and in my case: the schema found at w3.org/2001/XMLSchema ? [named however I choose to name it?)?

To use either override (in XSD 1.1) or redefine (in 1.0 or 1.1), you will need to point to a schemaLocation for the schema you are modifying.  If you have a local copy of the schema for schema documents, you can certainly point to it, but it's equally possible to point to the copy on the W3C server.  So:  no, you don't "need" to have a local copy.  You may well want to, though:  W3C's servers take a beating from software that tries to dereference DTDs and schema documents every time it parses an XML document, and W3C's system administrators have responded by making their servers respond very slowly to such requests.  A local copy if thus likely to be more convenient, even though it's in no sense required.

> 1(b). When I try and save the local copy of the schema found at w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, I get validation errors for that schema, citing that 'xs:occurs' is already declared.' If I comment out that attributeGroup, I get similar errors throughout.

When you try to *save* it?  That sounds as if your file system were performing schema validation on files you save; that would be novel behavior.  I suspect that the validation errors you are seeing are arising in some other context; without knowing what the validator is trying to do and how it was invoked, it's hard to tell just what's going on here.  The message about attribute group xs:occurs already being declared suggests that your validator is seeing the schema for schema documents twice; either because it's got knowledge of the namespace built in (in which case you may not be able to make your validator use a modified schema for the namespace at all) or because of an error in the way you have put your schema together, or because of an error in the way the validator was invoked.

> 1 (c). Note that I have included the XMLSchema.dtd header at the top of my localy saved schema (and have the dtd locally saved) the attributes of my local schema:

```
    <!DOCTYPE schema SYSTEM "XMLSchema.dtd"> 
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               blockDefault="#all" 
               elementFormDefault="qualified" 
               version="1.0" 
               xmlns:xs="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xml:lang="EN" 
               xmlns:hfp="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-hasFacetAndProperty"
               finalDefault="" 
               attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

No obvious problem here.  The document type declaration is not strictly speaking required, but if you are not encountering 'could not find DTD' errors, it is probably doing no harm.

> 1 (c) (continued) When I delete xmlns:xs="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; (which I suspected would get rid of the duplicate definition errors, I get another error that states "Element 'xs:schema' has no declaration for an attribute named 'xmlns:hfp'" Can you or anyone tell me what the I'm doing wrong here?

You have a document which uses the namespace prefix `xs` on virtually every element.  You do *not* want to delete the namespace binding for that prefix.

Making an XSD validator use a modified form of the schema for schema documents is, in its way, an advanced topic in the use of XSD.  (Any time you use language L to describe and potentially to modify language L, it's easy to work yourself into confusions between the object language and the metalanguage.  Ask your nearest guru how long it took them to understand the first meta-circular interpreter they ever studied.)

If you are at the stage of your work with XML and XSD that you have any doubts as to the likely effect of deleting a namespace declaration in one of your schema documents, you may find the task you have undertaken a very challenging exercise.  I won't say you shouldn't spend time on it, for much the same reason I wouldn't tell a teenager not to spend time rebuilding an engine.  It may be fun, and you may learn a lot.  But if you're not doing this as an end in itself, you need to know that it's not going to be quick or simple.  You are unlikely to get it to work by fiddling with namespace declarations in this way.  (In this context, I recommend you read [the story of Tom Knight and the Lisp Machine](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/koans.html).)

Comment: Ok. A number of issues have come up as I have tried to implement your suggestions:

1. The xsd validator my editor uses is only compatible with xsd version 1.0. Nonetheless, I've attempted to acheive my goal with 1.0 based off your example above. In doing so, I've encountered the following issues/questions:

Comment: 1(a). I still need to have a local copy of the schema used to validate schema documents, right?  (in your case: sfsd-11.xsd, and in my case: the schema found at http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema ? [named however I choose to name it?)?

Comment: 1(b). When I try and save the local copy of the schema found at http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, I get validation errors for that schema, citing that 'xs:occurs' is already declared.'  If I comment out that attributeGroup, I get similar errors throughout.

Comment: 1 (c). Note that I have included the XMLSchema.dtd header at the top of my localy saved schema (and have the dtd locally saved) the attributes of my local schema:

<!DOCTYPE schema SYSTEM "XMLSchema.dtd">
"<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 blockDefault="#all" 
 elementFormDefault="qualified" 
 version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xml:lang="EN" 
 xmlns:hfp="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-hasFacetAndProperty" 
 finalDefault="" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

Comment: 1 (c) (continued) 
When I delete xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" (which I suspected would get rid of the duplicate definition errors, I get another error that states "Element 'xs:schema' has no declaration for an attribute named 'xmlns:hfp'"

Can you or anyone tell me what the I'm doing wrong here?